# WSO2 waiting for required OSGI services during startup

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse

I'm running WSO2 AM 1.10.0 in cluster node on two virtual machines on my PC (one acting as manager node the other is a worker node). Recently I had to re-install my PC from scratch with Windows 10, and occasionally after restart I receive the following warning messages repeating again and again:

```
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.AppDeployerServiceComponent} 
   Waiting for required OSGi services: 
       org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.service.SynapseAppDeployerService,
       org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.services.SynapseEnvironmentService,
WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} 
   Waiting for required OSGi services: 
       org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.service.CappDeploymentService,
       org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.common.IServerAdmin,
       org.wso2.carbon.throttling.agent.ThrottlingAgen,
```

It does not happen each time, but when it happens it does not allow WSO2 to start for a long time. Any possible reason why it happens?

Comment: This is due to the OSGi dependencies are not satisfied properly.

Comment: How can i trace what is missing? I guess it is something in the running environment (port, memory, etc) cause i did not change anything in the code/ configuration since the time it did start. Only eestarted the pc. But not sure how to find out what is missing or blocking.

Comment: Start the server with OSGi console and type ls it will list down all the service components. Check the components which are not  in activated state

Comment: I am having the same error iwth no osgi how can i remove the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the visual SVN server I am using (Visual SVN on the host of the virtual boxes) sometimes not runs correctly after restart, and requires manual restart.

Comment: how is that connected to wso2 start up?